# Странный font-size в CSS

Tags: css, шрифты

Поступил сайт на доработку, где по всему `style.css` наблюдаю похожие конструкции: `font-size:181.25%16px;`. Меняются только последние значения (16px).

Единственный нормальный `font-size` указан у `body = 18px`.

Теперь сам вопрос: что это, от куда это, оно вообще реально? Может такое генерирует какой-то конструктор сайтов?

Comment: Может быть это какая-то защита от того, что 16px; не сработает? В этом случае будет 181.25% . Но если чество муть какя-то

Answer (score 2):

В параметре указан и **относительный** (в %), и **абсолютный** (в px, пикселях) размер шрифта. Сейчас в CSS-параметрах можно указывать даже вычисления. Для примера:

```
font-size: calc(100vw / 40);
background-position: calc(50% + 20px) calc(50% + 20px), 50% 50%
```

Согласно [Relative font-size калькулятору](http://tools.the-echoplex.net/font-size/#16), 181.25% это есть скалирование 16px до 29px.

**UPDATE:** Это ошибка синтаксиса
Получен однозначный ответ на папе: [Font-size CSS parameter looks like font-size:181.25%16px;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783846/font-size-css-parameter-looks-like-font-size181-2516px/)

Comment: И как же оно по-твоему должно работать?

Comment: Думаю, я повторю комментарий Романа под самим вопросом. Не знаю *зачем это*, но эмпирическим путем я установил **что это** :)

Comment: Надо добавить что в стандартах и спецификациях W3C я такой формы записи не нашёл.

Comment: Хром эту штуку зачёркивает, как некорректную. Где это работает?

Comment: Хм... а у меня Chrome валидировал и корректно отобразил документ с содержимым `<p style="font-size:181.25%16px">Test</p>`

Comment: Открой developer tools и посмотри в elements -> styles, что это значение зачёркнуто как невалидное.

Comment: Разные dev tools могут использовать разные спецификации DOM'а. Поэтому где-то подсвечивается ошибка, а где-то нет. Если же ты создашь простой html-документ с единственной строчкой `<p style="font-size:181.25%16px">Test</p>` то он великолепно валидируется и откроется Хромом. Можно потом сделать View Source и там тоже не будет проблем.

Comment: @Qwertiy ты абсолютно прав. Я просто не тот View Source посмотрел. Сейчас получен однозначный ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783846/font-size-css-parameter-looks-like-font-size181-2516px/ - ошибка синтаксиса.

Answer (score 0):

Это невалидная конструкция. Так что варианты следующие:

- это костыль под какой-то конкретный браузер - мне о таком неизвестно
- это какая-то ошибка компиляции стилей
- кто-то просто не знал, что пишет и написал бред...